SciPy binom.logsf - just a convenience function?
I thought that scipy.stats.binom.log* family of functions were able to return a greater range of values because somehow, they kept all computations in log-space.
But this example shows that both binom.logsf and binom.sf fail due to precision for the same inputs so the log* functions are just convenience functions i.e. equivalent to the code log(binom.sf())
QUESTION
Is this the expected behavior or is there a configuration step I missed?
for n in range(n_min_max, n_min_max + 20):        
    p_trial_log = binom.logsf(n, N, p_let)
    p_trial = binom.sf(n, N, p_let)
    print(f"args = {n}, {N}, {p_let}")
    print(f"p_trial_log={p_trial_log:.1e}")
    print(f"p_trial=    {p_trial:.4e}")
    print(f"p_trial_exp={exp(p_trial_log):.4e}")
    print("")

Output:
args = 42, 100000, 4e-10
p_trial_log=-5.6e+02
p_trial=    1.2691e-242
p_trial_exp=1.2691e-242

args = 43, 100000, 4e-10
p_trial_log=-5.7e+02
p_trial=    1.1532e-248
p_trial_exp=1.1532e-248

args = 44, 100000, 4e-10
p_trial_log=-5.8e+02
p_trial=    1.0246e-254
p_trial_exp=1.0246e-254

args = 45, 100000, 4e-10
p_trial_log=-6.0e+02
p_trial=    8.9059e-261
p_trial_exp=8.9059e-261

args = 46, 100000, 4e-10
p_trial_log=-6.1e+02
p_trial=    7.5760e-267
p_trial_exp=7.5760e-267

args = 47, 100000, 4e-10
p_trial_log=-6.3e+02
p_trial=    6.3104e-273
p_trial_exp=6.3104e-273

args = 48, 100000, 4e-10
p_trial_log=-6.4e+02
p_trial=    5.1488e-279
p_trial_exp=5.1488e-279

args = 49, 100000, 4e-10
p_trial_log=-6.5e+02
p_trial=    4.1171e-285
p_trial_exp=4.1171e-285

args = 50, 100000, 4e-10
p_trial_log=-6.7e+02
p_trial=    3.2274e-291
p_trial_exp=3.2274e-291

args = 51, 100000, 4e-10
p_trial_log=-6.8e+02
p_trial=    2.4814e-297
p_trial_exp=2.4814e-297

args = 52, 100000, 4e-10
p_trial_log=-7.0e+02
p_trial=    1.8718e-303
p_trial_exp=1.8718e-303

args = 53, 100000, 4e-10
p_trial_log=-7.1e+02
p_trial=    1.3858e-309
p_trial_exp=1.3858e-309

args = 54, 100000, 4e-10
p_trial_log=-7.3e+02
p_trial=    1.0073e-315
p_trial_exp=1.0073e-315

args = 55, 100000, 4e-10
p_trial_log=-7.4e+02
p_trial=    7.2134e-322
p_trial_exp=7.2134e-322

args = 56, 100000, 4e-10
p_trial_log=-inf
p_trial=    0.0000e+00
p_trial_exp=0.0000e+00

args = 57, 100000, 4e-10
p_trial_log=-inf
p_trial=    0.0000e+00
p_trial_exp=0.0000e+00

args = 58, 100000, 4e-10
p_trial_log=-inf
p_trial=    0.0000e+00
p_trial_exp=0.0000e+00

args = 59, 100000, 4e-10
p_trial_log=-inf
p_trial=    0.0000e+00
p_trial_exp=0.0000e+00

args = 60, 100000, 4e-10
p_trial_log=-inf
p_trial=    0.0000e+00
p_trial_exp=0.0000e+00

args = 61, 100000, 4e-10
p_trial_log=-inf
p_trial=    0.0000e+00
p_trial_exp=0.0000e+00


It depends on the distribution.
logsf() is implemented within either rv_discrete or rv_continuous, depending on whether you are dealing with a discrete or continuous distribution. logsf() does some error checking, then calls _logsf() to actually calculate the probability.
In some SciPy distributions, _logsf() is not implemented. In these cases, the superclass implements it by calling the distribution-specific _sf() (which is defined for all distributions) and taking the logarithm of that number. For very small probabilities, this runs into floating point underflow.
For other distributions, the risk of underflow has been recognized and mitigated by some alternate calculation. For example, the normal distribution has a _logsf() implementation which avoids taking the logarithm of the survival function. Here's what that looks like.
Because the class for the binomial distribution lacks a _logsf() method, it instead calls _sf() and takes the logarithm of that value.
Finally, patches are welcome. If you know of a way of calculating the logged survival function for any distribution, which has better accuracy than what is currently done, you should open an issue with SciPy.

Tracing though the docs and [source], for class rv_generic, _logsf is related to _sf with
def _logsf(self, x, *args):
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
        return log(self._sf(x, *args))

See also the source of logsf for rv_generic, which has some additional input processing, but ends up calling the above generic _logsf.

... and binom_gen does not define _logsf. Therefore, calling binom.logsf goes through the "generic" code path indeed.

Correct, without a class specific implementation, the inherited generic method is used.
